# Интеграция 1C с UMI.CMS

Tags: umi, интеграция

Добрый день. У меня есть файл `import.xml` из `1С` и старый файл импорта под `UMI.CMS`, а теперь мне надо сделать правильный файл импорта из 1С в `UMI`. Может есть руководства какие-то в интернете? У самого найти не получилось ничего толкового.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не достаточно точный отвечу в общем. Если файл в формате CommerceML 2.0 и umiDump 2.0 то [импорт можно настроить в модуле "Обмен данными"](http://help.docs.umi-cms.ru/rabota_s_modulyami/modul_obmen_dannymi/import_dannyh/) этот механизм кастомизируется подробнее в UMI.CMS Интеграция с 1С еще может быть полезный материал [xmlImporter Класс для импорта данных в формате umiDump 2.0](http://api.docs.umi-cms.ru/spravochnik_po_klassam_yadra_umicms/raznoe/xmlimporter/).